# Why 'dict(Count(list)) does not work in python for windows?

Tags: python, windows, bioinformatics

```
def codon_usage(seq, aminoacid):
    """Provides the frequency of each codon encoding a given aminoacid in a DNA sequence"""
    tmpList = []
    for i in range(0, len(seq) - 2, 3):
        if DNA_Codons[seq[i:i + 3]] == aminoacid:
                tmpList.append(seq[i:i + 3])

    freqDict = **dict(Counter**(tmpList))
    totalWight = sum(freqDict.values())
    for seq in freqDict:
        freqDict[seq] = round(freqDict[seq] / totalWight, 2)
    return freqDict
```

Hello, I was trying this code but I have a problem for making it run. 'dict(Counter(list)' is supposed to retrieve a dictionary where key is my sequence and the value is how many times that key appears. But, the error message is that 'count' variable is not defined. This code is from a video which uses Linux
Can someone help me?

Comment: `Counter` is **not** defined anywhere. This isn't a Windows things. Likely, that is mean to be from the `collections` module

Comment: you're all right! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `Counter`:

```py
from collections import Counter
```

Comment: can I ask you another question? Where can I find information about these collections? I've been looking up in Python's documentary in dictionaries and list sections but I've found nothing

Comment: @Christ14n97 I think this is what you're looking for: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Comment: absolutely grateful!